# Parsing XML With Google Maps Directions API fails

Tags: android, xml, api, google-maps, directions

first of all, actually I have a problem in Android programming but maybe I should describe the case..

I want to make Android application which can show the distance between two locations based on their latitude and longitude..
I store those coordinates in my SQLite database..

To determine the distance, I use Google Maps API Direction and parse it with XML Parser since the result I want in XML format. It works fine in my emulator and real device. But, after several days, it shows the null result and I don't know why since my code doesn't show any error.

Then, I try to throw the instruction in http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

And I try this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-7.966071,112.60774&destination=-7.963988,112.607487&sensor=false&units=metric

The result is in XML format, but it shows:

```
> <DirectionsResponse> <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status>
> </DirectionsResponse>
```

So, I read again and find this:

> Usage Limits
>
> Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   directions requests per day. Individual directions requests may
>   contain up to 8 intermediate waypoints in the request. Google Maps
>   Premier customers may query up to 100,000 directions requests per day,
>   with up to 23 waypoints allowed in each request.
>
> Additionally, note that Directions API URLs are restricted to 2048
>   characters, before URL Encoding. As some Directions service URLs may
>   involve many locations along a path, be aware of this limit when
>   constructing your URLs.
>
> Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with
>   displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without
>   displaying a map for which directions data was requested is
>   prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates
>   copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some
>   fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API
>   Terms of Service License Restrictions.

Is it any relationship between those???
I tried many times and got nothing..

So, is there any 'limitations' to use API Directions??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps detects automated query request and blocks them. Perhaps your application behaved in such a way. (Behaviour like requesting for directions after fixed intervals of time. Or too many queries per second)

> This limit is enforced to prevent abuse and/or repurposing of the
>   Geocoding API, and this limit may be changed in the future without
>   notice. Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse
>   of the service. If you exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the
>   service, the Geocoding API may stop working for you temporarily. If
>   you continue to exceed this limit, your access to the Geocoding API
>   may be blocked.

I suggest that you give it a break, or you might get blocked.

Comment: uhhmm, I really don't get about your answer. But, after I checked again with throwing the URL that I described aboved, it always show OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. I don't try it in my Android application but with my ordinary browser such as Firefox and Chrome.. 

any idea about this???

Comment: ok, and now I got it.. But, how do I know if I am blocked?? and how many limitations that I should obey??
and also does 24-hour limit mean that if I use that API and then I can't use it again in next day??